# Rewrite rule for goto functionality

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, goto

on a page i have set the goto functionality, so that when I click on a link the browser takes me to the correspondent div. But in the URL above it shows index.html#c26 for example .How can I let it show a name instead of that symbol? Should I use Rewrite Rules in htaccess ? if yes , could you give me please a simple example. thanks

Comment: Instead of what symbol? The hash?

Comment: the hash and all what comes after (#c26) .. because this was automatically generated by typo3